# PHP Propel cache query on runtime

Tags: php, propel, query-cache, propel2

Good morning,

We are using propel combine with Thelia. But for some query we would like to add cache. Is it possible to set cache config on runtime ?

For example, we need the id of the postal delivery mode, we use this query often, so I would like for it to be cached.

Thanks

Marine

Comment: Is this already indexed at the database level?

Comment: Do you means if our databases schema use indexes ? Yes it does but I don't see the relations ^^